# Datamatrix 16x48 with TCPDF library for PHP

Tags: php, tcpdf, datamatrix

i need to print a datamatrix code on my pdf.

Requested format by documentation is 16x48 datamatrix ECC 200.

Example code is this: 18800000571920119916120010109364801000000128003896

Result must be this one: [image]

I'm using TCPDF library for PHP, and this is my code:

```
$code = '18800000571920119916120010109364801000000128003896';
$style = array(
    'border' => true,
    'vpadding' => 'auto',
    'hpadding' => 'auto',
    'fgcolor' => array(0,0,0),
    'bgcolor' => false, //array(255,255,255)
    'module_width' => 1, // width of a single module in points
    'module_height' => 1, // height of a single module in points
    'position' => 'S'
);
$pdf->write2DBarcode($code, 'DATAMATRIX', 150, 10, 80, 50, $style, 'N', true);
```

In the include/barcodes/datamatrix.php file, i commented all the sizes of datamatrix leaving only 16x48 (because if i leave all, i get a 32x32 size by standard).

This is what i get:

[image]

Left part is pretty similar to the correct result, but the right part is completely white!!!

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Any recommendations on how this can be done to get a 16x48 rectangular datamatrix

Answer (score 0):

The Datamatrix Constructor check the most suitable form size to use regarding the given data. The form definitions (square and rectangle) are defined in the Datamatrix class (l.147 to l.177). For test purpose I put rectangles form definitions before the squares. It generates a 16x48 datamatrix if the given data are not too long but I didn't test the data integrity. include/barcodes/datamatrix.php :

```
protected $symbattr = array(
    // rectangular form (currently unused) ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    array(0x008,0x012,0x006,0x010,0x008,0x012,0x006,0x010,0x001,0x001,0x001,0x005,0x007,0x001,0x005,0x007), // 8x18
    array(0x008,0x020,0x006,0x01c,0x008,0x010,0x006,0x00e,0x001,0x002,0x002,0x00a,0x00b,0x001,0x00a,0x00b), // 8x32
    array(0x00c,0x01a,0x00a,0x018,0x00c,0x01a,0x00a,0x018,0x001,0x001,0x001,0x010,0x00e,0x001,0x010,0x00e), // 12x26
    array(0x00c,0x024,0x00a,0x020,0x00c,0x012,0x00a,0x010,0x001,0x002,0x002,0x00c,0x012,0x001,0x00c,0x012), // 12x36
    array(0x010,0x024,0x00e,0x020,0x010,0x012,0x00e,0x010,0x001,0x002,0x002,0x020,0x018,0x001,0x020,0x018), // 16x36
    array(0x010,0x030,0x00e,0x02c,0x010,0x018,0x00e,0x016,0x001,0x002,0x002,0x031,0x01c,0x001,0x031,0x01c),  // 16x48

    // square form ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    array(0x00a,0x00a,0x008,0x008,0x00a,0x00a,0x008,0x008,0x001,0x001,0x001,0x003,0x005,0x001,0x003,0x005), // 10x10
    array(0x00c,0x00c,0x00a,0x00a,0x00c,0x00c,0x00a,0x00a,0x001,0x001,0x001,0x005,0x007,0x001,0x005,0x007), // 12x12
    array(0x00e,0x00e,0x00c,0x00c,0x00e,0x00e,0x00c,0x00c,0x001,0x001,0x001,0x008,0x00a,0x001,0x008,0x00a), // 14x14
    array(0x010,0x010,...
```